# how do i get the minikube nodes in a local cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Im trying to set up a local cluster using VM and minikube, as Id been reading its only possible to use it for local purposes, but id like to join a secondary machine, and im searching a way to create the join and hash.

Answer (score 21):

You can easily do it in case your minikube machine is using VirtualBox.

1. Start the minikube:

   ```
   $ minikube start --vm-driver="virtualbox"
   ```
2. Check the versions of kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl in minikube and print join command:

   ```
   $ kubectl version

   $ minikube ssh
   $ kubelet --version
   $ kubeadm token create --print-join-command
   ```
3. Create a new VM in VirtualBox. I've used Vagrant to create Ubuntu 16lts VM for this test. Check that the minikube and the new VM are in the same host-only VM network.
   You can use anything that suits you best, but the packages installation procedure would be different for different Linux distributions.
4. (On the new VM.) Add repository with Kubernetes:

   ```
   $ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
   $ cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
   deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
   EOF
   $ apt-get update
   ```
5. (On the new VM.)Install the same version of kubelet kubeadm and other tools on the new VM (1.10.0 in my case)

   ```
   $ apt-get -y install ebtables ethtool docker.io apt-transport-https kubelet=1.10.0-00 kubeadm=1.10.0-00
   ```
6. (On the new VM.)Use your join command from the step 2. IP address  should be from the VM Host-Only-Network. Only having Nat networks didn't work well in my case.

   ```
   $ kubeadm join 192.168.xx.yy:8443 --token asdfasf.laskjflakflsfla --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:shfkjshkfjhskjfskjdfhksfh...shdfk
   ```
7. (On the main host) Add network solution to the cluster:

   ```
   $ kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml
   ```
8. (On the main host) Check your nodes and pods using kubectl:

   ```
   $ kubectl get nodes:

   NAME            STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
   minikube        Ready     master    1h        v1.10.0
   ubuntu-xenial   Ready     <none>    36m       v1.10.0

   $ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
   NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
   kube-system   calico-etcd-982l8                          1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-79dccdc4cc-66zxm   1/1       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   calico-node-9sgt5                          1/2       Running   13         10m       10.0.2.15    ubuntu-xenial
   kube-system   calico-node-qtpg2                          2/2       Running   0          10m       10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   etcd-minikube                              1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   heapster-6hmhs                             1/1       Running   0          1h        172.17.0.4   minikube
   kube-system   influxdb-grafana-69s5s                     2/2       Running   0          1h        172.17.0.5   minikube
   kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube                1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                    1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube           1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-tzc4r                  3/3       Running   0          1h        172.17.0.2   minikube
   kube-system   kube-proxy-vl5mq                           1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   kube-proxy-xhv8s                           1/1       Running   2          35m       10.0.2.15    ubuntu-xenial
   kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                    1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-7gf4j      1/1       Running   0          1h        172.17.0.3   minikube
   kube-system   storage-provisioner                        1/1       Running   0          1h        10.0.2.15    minikube
   ```

Comment: please share the vagrantfile

Comment: why is the 'network solution" necessary? What does it do? Im concerned that its only for k8s 1.7. If its necessary for multi-node why is it not built into k8s? I read the yaml file and its a daemonset, etcd thing, a bunch of pods and a service.

Comment: Network solution is required to communicate with pods on different node. It’s still required for the latest version of k8s. It is not built-in to k8s because there are more than one network addon exist. It’s up to you to decide which addon you want to use. 192.168.0.0/16 subnet is default for calico addon. If you want to use flannel you need to adjust its yaml file before applying it to the cluster.

Comment: I stuck at step6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179194/can-join-the-cluster-but-unable-to-fetch-kubeadm-config

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with minikube. With minikube, the operating domain is a single laptop or local machine. You can't join an additional node, you'll need to build a whole cluster using something like [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/)

Comment: This probably was true back in 2018, but as of 2021 you can simulate multiple nodes of the cluster on one physical box using minikube. See `minikube node add` and other commands.
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/node/#synopsis-1