# What is minikube config specifying?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

According to the [minikube handbook](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/) the configuration commands are used to "Configure your cluster". But what does that mean?

If I set cpus and memory then are these the max values the cluster as a whole can ever consume?

Are these the values it will reserve on the host machine in preparation for use?

Are these the values that are handed to the control plane container/VM and now I have to specify more resources when making a worker node?

What if I want to add another machine (VM or bare metal) and add its resources in the form of a worker node to the cluster? From the looks of it I would have to delete that cluster, change the configuration, then start a new cluster with the new configuration. That doesn't seem scalable.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hello, by setting the `$ minikube start --cpus=X --memory=Y` you are telling to the `driver` (like for example `Virtualbox`) to use at max `X` cpus and `Y` memory (you are in fact creating a `VM`). It's the max that your Kubernetes cluster (single node) could use. This does not apply to the `$ minikube node add` as it would be a separate machine with it's own allocation. If you go for the `$ minikube start --cpus=X ... --nodes=2` each machine will have it's own limit ( 2*X and 2*Y). Have you seen this docs by any chance: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/node/?

Comment: I have not seen the node docs. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question:

> If I set cpus and memory then are these the max values the cluster as a whole can ever consume?

In short. It will be a limit for the whole resource (either a `VM`, a container, etc. depending on a `--driver` used). It will be used for the underlying OS, Kubernetes components and the workload that you are trying to run on it.

> Are these the values it will reserve on the host machine in preparation for use?

I'd reckon this would be related to the `--driver` you are using and how its handling the resources. I personally doubt it's reserving the 100% of `CPU` and `memory` you've passed in the `$ minikube start` and I'm more inclined to the idea that it uses how much it needs during specific operations.

> Are these the values that are handed to the control plane container/VM and now I have to specify more resources when making a worker node?

By default, when you create a `minikube` instance with: `$ minikube start ...` you will create a single node cluster capable of being a `control-plane` node and a `worker` node simultaneously. You will be able to run your workloads (like an `nginx-deployment` without adding additional node).

You can add a node to your `minikube` ecosystem with just: `$ minikube node add`. This will make another node marked as a `worker` (with no `control-plane` components). You can read more about it here:

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Tutorials: Multi node](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/multi_node/)*

> What if I want to add another machine (VM or bare metal) and add its resources in the form of a worker node to the cluster? From the looks of it I would have to delete that cluster, change the configuration, then start a new cluster with the new configuration. That doesn't seem scalable.

As said previously, you don't need to delete the `minikube` cluster to add another node. You can run `$ minikube node add` to add a node on a `minikube` host. There are also options to `delete`/`stop`/`start` nodes.

**Personally** speaking if the workload that you are trying to run requires multiple nodes, I would try to consider other Kubernetes cluster built on top/with:

- `Kubeadm`
- `Kubespray`
- `Microk8s`

This would allow you to have more flexibility on where you want to create your Kubernetes cluster (as far as I know, `minikube` works within a single host (like your laptop for example)).

> A side note!
>
> There is an answer (written more than 2 years ago) which shows the way to add a Kubernetes cluster node to a `minikube` here :
>
> - *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: How do I get the minikube nodes in a local cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706547/12257134)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Create cluster kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes sigs: Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)*
- *[Microk8s.io](https://microk8s.io/)*